# Compiling java file in android runtime java

Tags: java, android, dex, android-runtime

I know this has been asked here and I have tried the suggested solutions but nothing yet to solve. I want to create an java compiler that could run in android in run time using button click but I can't find the right approach to solve the problem.
 I've managed to create the lexical,parser and semantic analyzer but I have no Idea  how I will convert the string into machine readable language and get the output of the code.
 I've tried to download repositories from github but most of  it uses Javax.tools api which is not supported in Android Studio. 
 I still don't understand much about dexing too..
 what approach could I use to solve this problem ?

Comment: your question is too broad. You want to create very complex app having totally no idea of how to do that.

Comment: to be precised, I'm creating java ide in android. but I'm having problem in compilation process

Comment: if possible,I'm looking for a way to import javax.tools library in android studio